# Error when I try to use a Dictionary <string, string> as a bindingcontext to my pin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to fit two strings into a bindingcontext into my pin so they can bring it to the next page when i click the pin.

Code runs but the clickevent gives me a crash.
I have commented where I get the error (`Specified cast is not valid`), i recieve it during the clickevent, when I try to click on a pin and push the info from the dictionary(pin.bindingcontext) to the next page.

```
   Dictionary<string,string> data = new Dictionary<string,string>();

   private async Task<List<Pin>> LoadData() 
   {
   var pins = new List<Pin> ();

   var getItems = await phpApi.getInfo ();

   data.Add("info1", phoneString); //phoneString is a string that I give a value below when I gather data.
   data.Add("info2", urlString); //urlString also a string.

   foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {


   nameString = currentItem ["name"].ToString (); 
   adressString = currentItem ["adress"].ToString (); 
   phoneString = currentItem ["phone"].ToString (); 
   urlString = currentItem ["URL"].ToString (); 

            var pin = new Pin ();
            pin.Label = nameString;
            pin.Address = adressString;
            pin.BindingContext = data; //here i add the dictionary
            pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1;
            pins.Add (pin);

  }
}

   void onButtonClicked1 (object s, EventArgs a)
   {

    Pin pin = (Pin)s;
    Dictionary<string,string> myData = (Dictionary<string,string>) pin.BindingContext; //ERROR here when I try to click on the pin: Specified cast is not valid.

    Navigation.PushModalAsync (new DetailPage(myData["info1"], myData["info2"] ));

    }

public DetailPage (object theInfo1, object theInfo2)
{

    labelOne.text = theInfo1;
    labelTwo.text = theInfo2;
}
```

Comment: what type is pin.BindingContext? It sure doesn't look like a Dictionary<string, string> which is why you're receiving the error

Comment: same error with object, object.

Comment: do pin.BindingContext.GetType().ToString() and see what the value is

Comment: When I run that command in th elog in my loop i get this: `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator'2[CoreLocation.CLPlacemark,Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position]`

Comment: And when you run it where the exception is thrown? I bet it's a different type

Comment: When I write out pin.bindingcontext in the log in my loop i get this `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator'2[CoreLocation.CLPlacemark,Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position]` which means it doesnt recieve the value i guess?

Comment: A system.InvalidCastException was thrown. this line right here:  `Dictionary<string,string> myData = (Dictionary<string,string>) pin.BindingContext;` if i replace it with object, object i get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107907/discussion-between-keyvan-sadralodabai-and-yannick).

Comment: Your code, as written, will not work.  1) you're adding phone and url to the dict outside of the loop  2) you only initialize your dictionary once, so every pin will have a reference to the same object